What is this temp folder for?
I'm using a RAM disk where I've placed the temp folder on Windows 10. However, a new temp folder named something like 'yk5rjwiy' is created shortly after each system startup, consuming about 5GB of storage. Based on the subfolder names, I suspect it might be related to Visual Studio. What is this folder for? I mean if it is needed everytime, it shouldn't be placed in a temp folder. And can I prevent this folder from being created?
Here is a part of the subfolder names of this folder.
Android.Manifest-8.0.100.34.0.95.AAC983D2140763370160
AndroidPlatformMAUI2.3C17EE37E5C5DAE41A58
AspNetCore.WebView.Maui.8.0.61.D5A77A10F8C58C52CEAD
Azure.Storage.Emulator.B21FD70BDD2C9D834662
Clide.E9D7D8A41970C116CB5B
Emsdk.6.Manifest-8.0.100.8.0.7.AAC2DB357CCFE52FB3C6
Emsdk.7.Manifest-8.0.100.8.0.7.7615BF7ECADBFCD70B98
Maui.Controls.8.0.61.B86DC4E3E11ADCD7EE7A
Maui.Controls.Build.Tasks.8.0.61.AED1083FF8E284E87F4D
Maui.Controls.Compatibility.8.0.61.553B729B8AC43E459C08
Maui.Controls.Core.8.0.61.10BFF40906715768E423
Maui.Controls.Xaml.8.0.61.3CAD876AA10C5206F5C4
Maui.Core.8.0.61.2DE98356E0729A1FECCB
Maui.Essentials.8.0.61.DA9C8EA7BA50C98D5E85
Maui.Graphics.8.0.61.55258A930D4CBE5BE50C
Maui.Graphics.Windows.8.0.61.E06EFEF8D4CFB85FD8DE
Maui.Resizetizer.8.0.61.F5BBFE20382814F0C9F4
Maui.Sdk.net8.8.0.61.7D5A32EE9B2F0EDD4A93
Maui.Templates.net8.8.0.61.1C24679408E78F31D82A
Microsoft.Android.Ref.34.34.0.95.AFEF3B8BDE93E421F714
Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-arm.34.0.95.3DA7223E84F77665C5CB
Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-arm64.34.0.95.A643185B8E735656F138
Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-x64.34.0.95.9EB941497709B39243F5
Microsoft.Android.Runtime.34.android-x86.34.0.95.002E53B7D2CB9E5B5FCD
Microsoft.Android.Sdk.net8.34.0.95.3EC16E1DB66B34E8B958
Microsoft.Android.Templates.34.0.95.A8DEF08C208E4ADAFE73
Microsoft.AOT.Cross.net7.android-arm.7.0.20.5612F76D2437DD558B2B
Microsoft.AOT.Cross.net7.android-arm64.7.0.20.AB65EECF2CF5230C620E
Microsoft.AOT.Cross.net7.android-x64.7.0.20.682CDC505681410655E5
Microsoft.AOT.Cross.net7.android-x86.7.0.20.C5AEF62523B7A9F3BD6F
Microsoft.AOT.Cross.net8.android-arm.8.0.7.08EEC1A43F405C79FF2B
Microsoft.AOT.Cross.net8.android-arm64.8.0.7.5C181902BDD67129A421
Microsoft.AOT.Cross.net8.android-x64.8.0.7.E77D5C473FC2C873F9DD
Microsoft.AOT.Cross.net8.android-x86.8.0.7.F030AAD9694F3DFE7D6D
Microsoft.AOT.Cross.net8.browser-wasm.8.0.7.52712C462CECC9CDBCF7
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SharedFramework.6.0.6.0.32-servicing.24314.5.57BF4B24A08C2EA6026A
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SharedFramework.6.0.6.0.32-servicing.24314.5.58BF6E581F416AEEF91D
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SharedFramework.8.0.8.0.7-servicing.24314.2.212DD33B6A0B230AB60D
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SharedFramework.8.0.8.0.7-servicing.24314.2.A33347DD79A51418E24F
Microsoft.AspNetCore.TargetingPack.6.0.6.0.32-servicing.24314.5.5DD11F1844F39FC86D6D
Microsoft.AspNetCore.TargetingPack.6.0.6.0.32-servicing.24314.5.7D06EED1AD4134077998
Microsoft.AspNetCore.TargetingPack.8.0.8.0.7-servicing.24314.2.B955195A328F2761F002
Microsoft.AspNetCore.TargetingPack.8.0.8.0.7-servicing.24314.2.ED0F47B7EB9DD04D5897
Microsoft.Build.7A6690EADA6671048E65
Microsoft.Build.Dependencies.EDBF30B044118826B4A6
Microsoft.Build.FileTracker.Msi.D9C1DD803F2B42900705
Microsoft.Build.UnGAC.DA04D174AD161A9E763C
Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi.EDEE87AC54B681F65C46
Microsoft.ClickOnce.BootStrapper.Msi.Resources.5DD20B4CFF86D37C274A
Microsoft.ClickOnce.SignTool.Msi.1E1E0277694400037A06
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilers.0B69F79C58DCF953426B
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExpressionEvaluator.409A21FA4E02D70068D4
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualStudio.ServiceHub.Setup.x64.DAE3F3004A72C3FDA6F9
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualStudio.Setup.599B433D9882029B151A
Microsoft.Developer.IdentityServiceGS.4339CF00D2B9EFEC6163
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.BenchmarkDotNet.8EA465883266D4BDCFC1
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.BenchmarkDotNet.Resources.687E098BD3F8281793D7
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.BenchmarkDotNet.Targeted.2EE610001E62E1CF465C
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Collection.DC96ACC2F693600471E3
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Collection.ExternalDependencies.x64.F1DAA574D8FC2AA7CDF2
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Collection.Service.8C25FB5B9C8CF42492B2
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.CpuSampling.79E4A9B10F2A21D0A0CB
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.CpuSampling.Resources.CE9ED508B9B1181C923F
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.CpuSampling.Targeted.CC4B0E5F64559B1A4864
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DatabaseTool.9FA6969AD022C32A200B
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DatabaseTool.Resources.331A2E5B17DA3CCDAD79
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DatabaseTool.Targeted.9EDAD9E2637AE1705D5A
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DotNetAsync.A084935F60BEE62E25BC
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DotNetAsync.Resources.6BEB733E8FB9015EEF0F
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DotNetAsync.Targeted.BE3960A0EBDF193096B7
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DotNetCountersTool.9220376F36B9FB9C02D3
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DotNetCountersTool.Resources.3F0E1FB805A80A7E7E4F
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DotNetCountersTool.Targeted.E9B2B4757266B2620517
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DotNetObjectAlloc.CEA1528754073C51CB27
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DotNetObjectAlloc.Resources.7A38673E32707C6AB2DC
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.DotNetObjectAlloc.Targeted.C04A147AE40BA25AC6CD
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.EventsViewerTool.1B838C7EA83774A64E08
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.EventsViewerTool.Resources.0481CB81645299A5E2F6
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.EventsViewerTool.Targeted.4D827F8CB523CAFD5EEC
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.FileIOTool.0785675E9F24C32BF759
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.FileIOTool.Resources.CE6E8E85CED814ECD742
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.FileIOTool.Targeted.28437B5479C5706AB1A8
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.IceCap.Instrumentation.8D39E62C0D2F4A673367
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.IceCap.Instrumentation.Resources.F231DD5474034DFCA99C
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Instrumentation.D29FEF55A57A906F8BEA
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Instrumentation.Resources.61ED54AD12649CF90AD0
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Instrumentation.Targeted.F0CB3F6DBBE71A7A562A
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Runtime.ExternalDependencies.5C4D895745523CADD9F4
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Runtime.ExternalDependencies.Targeted.98762DB04F30B8EB615E
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Runtime.F612DC524E6E29E2084D
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Runtime.Resources.21D708FC47CE94216743
Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Runtime.Targeted.C4F96E062BA9ACC20F75
Microsoft.DiaSymReader.F152882D2E87F8981C03
Microsoft.DiaSymReader.Native.3DA3EA9865DC312F3A8D
Microsoft.DiaSymReader.PortablePdb.1EB9230F9EE90197F47B
Microsoft.Emscripten.Cache.net7.7.0.20.5E83ECFF9617BBBA3559
Microsoft.Emscripten.Cache.net8.8.0.7.1D45CDAA96E74D76218B
Microsoft.Emscripten.Node.net7.7.0.20.07369F9B1A5C6346C942
Microsoft.Emscripten.Node.net8.8.0.7.01BAED4BD4F778F55681
Microsoft.Emscripten.Python.net7.7.0.20.E3AF111E4777FEF76720
Microsoft.Emscripten.Python.net8.8.0.7.72C7839DE47A49C98C0C
Microsoft.Emscripten.Sdk.net7.7.0.20.90A4CA5CB7AEA347228D
Microsoft.Emscripten.Sdk.net8.8.0.7.C9983BB0AF6EF3E5F36D
Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.15B89798006F5241C275
Microsoft.FSharp.Dependencies.C8EBA930489736DC4205
Microsoft.FSharp.IDE.1F891D243F5A893154B9
Microsoft.FSharp.SDK.A74B19A7E53047D5E9BC
Microsoft.FSharp.VSIX.Full.Core.4C5099EAE4354444A1DF
Microsoft.FSharp.VSIX.Templates.6383954AC2C00036F1ED
Microsoft.Icecap.Analysis.FC9ACE642455FAB1D235
Microsoft.Icecap.Analysis.Resources.A5137AD31C8BB6A92CE5
Microsoft.Icecap.Analysis.Resources.Targeted.6A6FEA3626AE118926CA
Microsoft.Icecap.Analysis.Targeted.E9A8004933C2247FC9C8
Microsoft.Icecap.Collection.Msi.CB10844249765CF58EA6
Microsoft.Icecap.Collection.Msi.Resources.B638AC3707465DBF083A
Microsoft.Icecap.Collection.Msi.Resources.Targeted.AC6EE7BCBEB4931F810E
Microsoft.Icecap.Collection.Msi.Targeted.987B4A907665DE590787
Microsoft.IntelliTrace.CollectorCab.4226B367B64D4F69B773
Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core.5FCED8D3ED29BCB0601A
Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core.Concord.B7CE2B92D445B6BB7694
Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core.Resources.99FCAE41569230CE4FB6
Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core.Targeted.5913ACDE02C450A26CB9
Microsoft.IntelliTrace.Core.Targeted.Resources.6F78114D4E94FC343628
Microsoft.IntelliTrace.DiagnosticsHub.2A4C39C6CD5CA778FD0E
Microsoft.IntelliTrace.DiagnosticsHub.Resources.1F79386EF930BFE0F868
Microsoft.iOS.Ref.17.2.8053.84F70B23B27BBCE6E8AB
Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.ios-arm64.17.2.8053.B6703007DD9A69651870
Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-arm64.17.2.8053.D905C0057B66930320BD
Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-x64.17.2.8053.F4CE109E5878FE2B0513
Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net7.16.4.7142.D6B5C4E4786398342A25
Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net8.17.2.8053.D8FC6F0959E662EAC1A0
Microsoft.iOS.Templates.net8.17.2.8053.8025109FF0DB3EA27FE6
Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk.Aliased.net7.16.4.7142.21DAAF9AEE48B54EF4D8
Microsoft.iOS.Windows.Sdk.Aliased.net8.17.2.8053.472202553E97EFB364CB
Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Manifest-8.0.100.17.2.8053.0C465F5466E21987A233
Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Ref.17.2.8053.C5E8145001966A019101
Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Runtime-arm64.17.2.8053.66A71985578AD9AE6150
Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Runtime-x64.17.2.8053.362298CA03C1C988A500
Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk.net7.16.4.7142.00A3C41181B067B76A4D
Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk.net8.17.2.8053.FBFD2011F3631AED36A4
Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Templates.net8.17.2.8053.740BCA9430BC8E4DF226
Microsoft.Mono.net7.android-arm.7.0.20.893DFE575A70037B9F7E
Microsoft.Mono.net7.android-arm64.7.0.20.F8C3266175CDEA03B07C
Microsoft.Mono.net7.android-x64.7.0.20.3430F7A745E9AC39109F
Microsoft.Mono.net7.android-x86.7.0.20.9EBBDE7845D2B5673A10
Microsoft.Mono.net7.ios-arm.7.0.20.3C202525E29C182552FF
Microsoft.Mono.net7.ios-arm64.7.0.20.CF330F37A35A2AC1CB7E
Microsoft.Mono.net7.iossimulator-arm64.7.0.20.2B70B3C346665119F45B
Microsoft.Mono.net7.iossimulator-x64.7.0.20.91DCDC3BC0D16788AC4D
Microsoft.Mono.net7.iossimulator-x86.7.0.20.88597F497B08F00CD68D
Microsoft.Mono.net7.maccatalyst-arm64.7.0.20.0AE81B49B528D2E3683F
Microsoft.Mono.net7.maccatalyst-x64.7.0.20.D483EFA48E44EEF89090
Microsoft.Mono.net8.android-arm.8.0.7.7EDB8285F6403E486045
Microsoft.Mono.net8.android-arm64.8.0.7.75C3CC83175DF3BEE846
Microsoft.Mono.net8.android-x64.8.0.7.BBDBEA413AC5AEEE25B7
Microsoft.Mono.net8.android-x86.8.0.7.05FB394E25623760ACFB
Microsoft.Mono.net8.browser-wasm.8.0.7.5AE9377ECD1277305D6F
Microsoft.Mono.net8.ios-arm64.8.0.7.03C875771486BF4EF55E
Microsoft.Mono.net8.iossimulator-arm64.8.0.7.5D1A887F7B457AA6501C
Microsoft.Mono.net8.iossimulator-x64.8.0.7.C070D1B139314EA0E1FB
Microsoft.Mono.net8.maccatalyst-arm64.8.0.7.B70EC72375DE0F1DAA1C
Microsoft.Mono.net8.maccatalyst-x64.8.0.7.882B8D5E8BE5AA64E679
Microsoft.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.net6.6.0.32.6FFCAB347D2D47C35D2A
Microsoft.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.net7.7.0.20.873C1F663E6ADF270BF2
Microsoft.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.net8.8.0.7.A099EEAD0E959D3B2C97
Microsoft.MonoTargets.Sdk.net6.6.0.32.C1EFEFBDD8D35B4E1F1E
Microsoft.MonoTargets.Sdk.net7.7.0.20.712F1FEC5530F85528E7
Microsoft.MonoTargets.Sdk.net8.8.0.7.C74FC2AC0BBF1C527DB0
Microsoft.MSHtml.35F172F4C07FE73F0A72
Microsoft.Net.8.0.Runtime.AE499B557A2AA4D47B69
Microsoft.Net.8.0.WindowsDesktop.Runtime.8DE8DC668479421E15D8
Microsoft.Net.Core.BootstrapperPackages.E0F712C799D901785A59
Microsoft.Net.Core.SDK.MSBuildExtensions.2A737373DE8DCFB489E7
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Aspire.Manifest-8.0.100.8.0.0.B41CF6953393030B5FEC
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.iOS.Manifest-8.0.100.17.2.8053.8E8788D12A903DBEEE09
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.macOS.Manifest-8.0.100.14.2.8053.3D11203794338D388530
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Maui.Manifest-8.0.100.8.0.61.E9030121E6353A4DD758
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.tvOS.Manifest-8.0.100.17.2.8053.796CBB3AE8E31F3DE2BC
Microsoft.NET.Workload.Emscripten.Current.Manifest-8.0.100.8.0.7.8F94911D5F8DB6405A0D
Microsoft.NetCore.AppHostPack.6.0.6.0.32.arm.0CCEDC917A074AC6C1D5
Microsoft.NetCore.AppHostPack.6.0.6.0.32.arm64.D0801071C5A6FECEA32D
Microsoft.NetCore.AppHostPack.6.0.6.0.32.x64.1CBE81B1602D9F0509A0
Microsoft.NetCore.AppHostPack.6.0.6.0.32.x86.A9802395487720FFDB84
Microsoft.NetCore.AppHostPack.8.0.8.0.7.arm64.CE4F87474CC8CE98154F
Microsoft.NetCore.AppHostPack.8.0.8.0.7.x64.84D314B850B4B4D808D1
Microsoft.NetCore.AppHostPack.8.0.8.0.7.x86.280FD3182F6ED12C55DA
Microsoft.NetCore.HostFXR.8.0.7.99BCB26626264F021F33
Microsoft.NetCore.HostFXR.8.0.7.A5BF88025EB0482DD334
Microsoft.NetCore.SdkPlaceholder.8.0.303-servicing.24317.8.1DA3367A21A637E7D5D6
Microsoft.NetCore.SharedFramework.6.0.6.0.32.0751B1461378C18E50D4
Microsoft.NetCore.SharedFramework.6.0.6.0.32.08DCCC8DB243C54AD195
Microsoft.NetCore.SharedFramework.8.0.8.0.7.076586C6A75B3E2757AF
Microsoft.NetCore.SharedFramework.8.0.8.0.7.3419F3DBCB09D59F1627
Microsoft.NetCore.SharedHost.8.0.0.5E9BD43DF50E615A3FBC
Microsoft.NetCore.SharedHost.8.0.0.7DDE29C2C6EC16D626A5
Microsoft.NetCore.TargetingPack.6.0.6.0.32.4217C351B6A8D4274965
Microsoft.NetCore.TargetingPack.6.0.6.0.32.82E26813BA31A3B51A7D
Microsoft.NetCore.TargetingPack.8.0.8.0.7.32D0B5CDDCCECC97BE87
Microsoft.NetCore.TargetingPack.8.0.8.0.7.940349E47E3AAABB1566
Microsoft.NetCore.TemplateLocator.266BFA295A7CB9809F89
Microsoft.NetCore.Templates.6.0.8.0.303-servicing.24317.8.C44A4BCABFFB220A5191
Microsoft.NetCore.Templates.8.0.8.0.303-servicing.24317.8.EDE486B755FD42658D5F
Microsoft.NetCore.Toolset.8.0.303.E0580E28F5DB539D237A
Microsoft.Publish.Framework.1C434E975F21CAE59818
Microsoft.Publish.Framework.Resources.36E890DB0A1E143C5859
Microsoft.ServiceHub.amd64.702C735B5AFFF4F55970
Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.amd64.7EA33B7634E6F071FB08
Microsoft.ServiceHub.ExtensibilityHost.amd64.40BDE0D3834A69431AEC
Microsoft.ServiceHub.Managed.5AD5B460C07D16E5D967
Microsoft.ServiceHub.Node.06D1FC5DCFCEE7E49FC6
Microsoft.SQL.ClickOnceBootstrapper.Msi.F76208075A848C5E24A6
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.ASAN.Headers.base.F13EBF9A31E603122A85
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.ASAN.X64.base.B6FFB6CDC8DBE8C0BA72
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.ASAN.X86.base.5AC5F39469026ABCDA77
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.ATL.Headers.base.A9A8F34DAB70567E7747
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.ATL.Source.base.94E273AEE4D418F308C7
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.ATL.X64.base.38BFCD43E22139291C5F
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.ATL.X86.base.50B9CAF60A93518907AB
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CA.Ext.Hostx64.Targetx64.base.6FBF42A9D3B1119903EF
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CA.Ext.Hostx64.Targetx64.Res.base.95B4AA75A856138D0825
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CA.Ext.Hostx64.Targetx86.base.96F7871106E7B3EC7556
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CA.Ext.Hostx64.Targetx86.Res.base.E08BD0418632D6FF4674
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CA.Ext.Hostx86.Targetx64.base.ECA5C88ACC32C37210D5
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CA.Ext.Hostx86.Targetx64.Res.base.066A3D36FA518BD2522B
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CA.Ext.Hostx86.Targetx86.base.590DE800C25F54A82067
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CA.Ext.Hostx86.Targetx86.Res.base.723283B7526A3BDEA044
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CA.Rulesets.base.EB30B7656A1C35575BD9
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.arm.OneCore.Desktop.base.C5A46A4522715E269DA8
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.Headers.base.4529B951A425346A23CB
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.Headers.Resources.242F3EEF6F2C4D7E6131
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.Headers.Resources.base.D0A8242196ED2BDB8A92
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.Redist.X64.base.70022D6639E82EBB14D2
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.Redist.x64.OneCore.Desktop.base.D5943648FE2249713312
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.Redist.X86.base.37A794B376021DFAA64F
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.Redist.x86.OneCore.Desktop.base.6DE63511CEEC8D21CCB9
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.Source.base.91E5EA3265C1275DFC1F
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.x64.Desktop.base.81AAEEA055EBC32B9124
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.x64.OneCore.Desktop.base.8C749A0787B9633AC4DC
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.x64.Store.base.14F6D3E1B1FEF8BFF58A
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.x86.Desktop.base.08F8F72DC99A9E958B02
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.x86.OneCore.Desktop.base.9578B38DBC061CF8D236
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.CRT.x86.Store.base.B4A7713C859F8C24B381
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.PGO.Headers.base.F78408B556C7EE7D2E6D
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.PGO.X64.base.4A33491EB996B03D8CB0
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.PGO.X86.base.FAD472DC368D1A1C0D14
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Prem.HostX64.TargetX64.Res.base.580023AC0D86E4EF851E
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Prem.HostX64.TargetX86.Res.base.DD453B6737D40ED78B8A
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Prem.Hostx86.Targetx64.Res.base.6334A3E60BA0F83848FB
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Prem.HostX86.TargetX86.Res.base.44B55F1426295AC12903
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Premium.Tools.HostX64.TargetX64.base.4DD67326BA7EBE88B1C2
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Premium.Tools.HostX64.TargetX86.base.8CE0F6F36711D7FB7390
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Premium.Tools.HostX86.TargetX64.base.2331C6AE87F367AC3590
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Premium.Tools.HostX86.TargetX86.base.4DC8C98AA7FEA76406A4
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Props.ATLMFC.A3D47767EE6811B0E778
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Props.EAAB7EE460908FB11CA5
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Props.x64.18C28B52FA0A1AEF4756
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Props.x86.260C3A438ADE9BBDF99E
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Servicing.082A78F41EA5C26F3A97
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Servicing.ATL.F78023CF10969AAC2A93
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Servicing.CAExtensions.8E16D6E8C997997EF006
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Servicing.CARulesets.71FB86EF0E7E594F4AAB
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Servicing.Compilers.F054836498E4B8658B97
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Servicing.CrtHeaders.400E27F31DEBB2C1C1EB
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Tools.Core.Props.EB8A9F862AD304F4B99D
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Tools.HostX64.TargetX64.base.F129ABA62ACD5FEEA8F3
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Tools.HostX64.TargetX64.Res.base.A3FBE76E69B01E72F488
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Tools.HostX64.TargetX86.base.860DA9166B8F4D8067F5
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Tools.HostX64.TargetX86.Res.base.1AACD978E865A064D805
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Tools.HostX86.TargetX64.base.B40FEA6C6087961C3147
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Tools.Hostx86.Targetx64.Res.base.9B6D6688AD0255D07C5C
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Tools.HostX86.TargetX86.base.68620A6DC5B954D89A49
Microsoft.VC.14.40.17.10.Tools.HostX86.TargetX86.Res.base.8711DB2AA9A4CEF1BE83
Microsoft.VisualCpp.ASAN.X86.0D4C25AA902740E00557
Microsoft.VisualCpp.ATL.Headers.5C34D3A96DBDF9A37883
Microsoft.VisualCpp.ATL.Source.6752AC0ED5D1BFE60A60
Microsoft.VisualCpp.ATL.X64.7ADD2FBED7AE0F0D7FED
Microsoft.VisualCpp.ATL.X86.76BA7A0610E037CF64AF
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CA.Ext.Hostx64.Targetx64.A88698EDA8596BED63EC
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CA.Ext.Hostx64.Targetx86.53F10AB9E701BFAE6CA1
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CA.Ext.Hostx86.Targetx64.E15DA8CB484F32919DAF
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CA.Ext.Hostx86.Targetx86.847F1D09D976E6C619D6
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CodeAnalysis.Extensions.FA3A4639FAD3804466B2
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Appx.ARM64.Msi.3D6BE2C4041E35DE9C73
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Appx.Desktop.110.Msi.8A8EC5E9B3CEF7756A8D
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Appx.Desktop.120.Msi.4D53B92B76ABA9A50FB6
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Appx.Desktop.140.Msi.7CB1D5471F96F8A389B0
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Appx.Msi.95C4F9E22EE38B4E1D43
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Appx.Resources.Msi.5D21DB1636389A39A7F5
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Appx.Universal.120.Msi.B13A5471351D4A9BC099
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.arm.OneCore.Desktop.9842F7351708A255B339
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.ClickOnce.Msi.A1E1CFA76138D3FEAD51
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Headers.A98195EAEEEF4B39E6C5
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Redist.Resources.574313A89A7A68DADF9E
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Redist.X64.3B61C64291C0C2F6F997
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Redist.x64.OneCore.Desktop.98D96FE59C2ADBF00082
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Redist.X86.2E4A70F004110CE3DA6C
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Redist.x86.OneCore.Desktop.D86E27347C860927A731
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.Source.2EE0D7634F6DF3F1719C
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.x64.Desktop.F0A3427E7C49DF85F0A1
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.x64.OneCore.Desktop.6204BBBF6CC636BA852D
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.x64.Store.865456A9A28755A4BB03
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.x86.Desktop.5C6A51B087447E2E1BC6
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.x86.OneCore.Desktop.55990F3BBAD480B8A729
Microsoft.VisualCpp.CRT.x86.Store.0D68F0A074A4823E0C6C
Microsoft.VisualCpp.DIA.SDK.86E6684EA2F3D6559BED
Microsoft.VisualCpp.PGO.Headers.7BDCB4681E39185FFF01
Microsoft.VisualCpp.PGO.X64.2611A7A7CC43A6CC9A82
Microsoft.VisualCpp.PGO.X86.46D658E6D872D172F5A3
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Premium.Tools.HostX64.TargetX64.9A988B8911D2ED59CBD6
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Premium.Tools.HostX64.TargetX86.335B794B367BC1A788D3
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Premium.Tools.HostX86.TargetX64.28CB60FF4E3A388478C1
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Premium.Tools.HostX86.TargetX86.C1320BD158B1AA21FBA3
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.34195ADF139C68D06400
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.41C761257C9B12BCD6EF
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.8B6C65F888F3103DBF39
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Redist.14.Latest.CB7968EBCECEC0C9A116
Microsoft.VisualCpp.RuntimeDebug.14.3D849307642652B03423
Microsoft.VisualCpp.RuntimeDebug.14.6B0291C3E1C5BBC61993
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Servicing.DIASDK.4320C9545B3CEF90216C
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Servicing.Redist.B3D5AF897E76DB0BDBD6
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.Common.Utils.A68556B73D1A2BF54DD2
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.Common.Utils.Resources.BB16B28DB709CEFCA9BE
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.Common.UtilsPrereq.5E1E70D70011E93C6437
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.Core.Resources.E861687C3749734A61A3
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.Core.x86.AB92A8D8C414A464D4E6
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.HostX64.TargetX64.68B4B15B617737D59471
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.HostX64.TargetX86.FE2F040E958669470DC0
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.HostX86.TargetX64.841F89CB3D1835BE0D99
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.Hostx86.Targetx64.Res.DBF38F1474D93F7AE278
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.HostX86.TargetX86.0AB6A4A8030AF029E996
Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.HostX86.TargetX86.Res.5CEB7E5CE937550C72F9
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Android.DeviceManager.FF11A96AC655C1F25E2E
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Android.SdkManager.1AF25933E6D135FC4705
Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppCapDesigner.1B652FF7A6D07478C740
Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppResponsiveness.F5C4CF3413351E9B22CD
Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppResponsiveness.Resources.1654C3B59DD8C9ACCA1A
Microsoft.VisualStudio.AppResponsiveness.Targeted.7661DF84CDE883C533B2
Microsoft.VisualStudio.AzureSDK.DDAD30A76B327DFBB761
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Blend.8EC0802D4ED02674882E
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Blend.Auto.FD0EFD4ADF1B5DB5EECF
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Blend.Msi.F417AA05BD9778777A79
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Blend.Resources.C2B5D626AB9880E2A7DF
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Branding.Community.1DDEA582C296016D4E98
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClickOnce.5FF9288A7465EB39A1E5
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClickOnce.Publish.19C18FBE29B3AFC3895E
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClickOnce.Resources.9474CC65BA348BAFF44B
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClientDiagnostics.DCBAC897131DD5BF7907
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClientDiagnostics.Resources.253EDFDF32BC15ADE293
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ClientDiagnostics.Targeted.58CD26343193DDA27500
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeSense.Community.3A815A59DC4F60CC041E
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeSense.Community.Resources.B4DD9237FB6774D57504
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.CSharp.Neutral.746A441E912B5D14F0AA
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.CSharp.Resources.Neutral.17917EEDD56D3E162D50
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.CSharp.Resources.Targeted.B2211F9CC4811E6AC0D2
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.CSharp.Targeted.B063871E302B5981DB2C
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Msi.75A4BEEB2A3CB50AB0DC
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Msi.Resources.D5784AAD422E24244B59
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.ProductArch.Neutral.BD85F94F999BF19730E6
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.ProductArch.NeutralExtra.CDD812B07E1107ACA119
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.ProductArch.Resources.Neutral.A677F99DE2E544C3DC49
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.ProductArch.Resources.NeutralExtra.CD903752AE3D2CEC25C0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.ProductArch.Resources.Targeted.0B28A94F4FFF1B4F7F45
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.ProductArch.Targeted.2E9D8FB3F4748EB6CC0C
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.ProductArch.TargetedExtra.5795A9D15FAEF4387321
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.Shared.Msi.DB2C2D1F34F667A9032D
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.VB.Neutral.26B42FBB58002AC35CC1
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.VB.Resources.Neutral.7FC70BD046AD70E0C64E
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.VB.Resources.Targeted.3B50FC724C9DF893B822
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.VB.Targeted.5EE7806A01FB3ECCAE6E
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.VB.x64.A1494794522C90F22C11
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.VB.x86.9909F1F75044802297EC
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.x64.CF0C91F0F86F4FF548A4
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community.x86.07C85FBC93848D59E4DC
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Connected.Auto.6C001A108DED4D9F73CA
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Connected.Auto.Resources.53DD11DFE7886F926387
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Connected.C443F55DAC284E04F607
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Connected.Resources.4149C03F4B7B60348048
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.Core.4F79271CC441D81D5251
Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedServices.Office365.8A802BEF56BC97C424B4
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreDotNet.C4249CCD1904C15E7D05
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreDotNet.Resources.AAF4AAD582934FB50FDA
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CoreEditor.4E93409BE088C3F1CF73
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.4EA39A5F560A3D202443
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.AzureAttach.5FB35AA9BDAEF67C857A
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.AzureAttach.Resources.7CA817152D593D533F43
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.BrokeredServices.CC42C58875715988F900
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.CollectionAgents.767B17A0D676D31B47D4
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.2E0DE1CFE8F59471FB52
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.Managed.76CB632AC619DF286DC9
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.Managed.Resources.45BACBDE5296478AAA5D
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.OneCore.arm.3B6361E6E8775F55386E
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.OneCore.arm.Resources.38295E209927A235039D
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.OneCore.arm64.77252D7F3B217A89A06C
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.OneCore.arm64.Resources.C234E76092D5A329E580
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.OneCore.ManagedSupport.8D90256E34497F5F733D
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.OneCore.x64.40E2B2D0F18B64DA1106
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.OneCore.x64.Resources.8BA943C3384D2B2BEE5D
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.OneCore.x86.8A928E311DCB53B6F9EF
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.OneCore.x86.Resources.9CD44485DA525EE45FBD
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.Remote.B52F501171E6272F1DAE
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.Remote.B7D5F4603E7F0E54BDA5
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.Remote.Resources.5C3020A1FF30F80AF6B9
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.Remote.Resources.D5D2B57A4C1A1D7E5C1E
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Concord.Resources.9464301B903A42E05C14
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.CoreClr.arm.FA005EDB652A7D0261E0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.CoreClr.arm64.7FA5E84B0A0BF0BDA4BD
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.CoreClr.x64.7F0E65FACF039CCE7B54
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.CoreClr.x86.4E6A007ACD73D8244E2A
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.JustInTime.DBC15A0FBD59486722A8
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Managed.73CD8E2BCA011D9F03AC
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Managed.Resources.F8CC471A9A67D18126A5
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.OneCore.arm.12A70CB31EBF8CB22CF0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.OneCore.arm.Resources.B916D88A50D11C2C8D01
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.OneCore.arm64.DD7DE86EF693AADD212A
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.OneCore.arm64.Resources.8537729F67B22EA6DD34
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.OneCore.ManagedSupport.65C93494E5990E77D285
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.OneCore.x64.02E70615A0FB0ED0C57B
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.OneCore.x64.Resources.23F6A252C440DFFB9728
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.OneCore.x86.7F31662ED0769B930596
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.OneCore.x86.Resources.421B7DFD17B53EB49130
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Package.DiagHub.Client.AEA8BCCCDD8224F5DF5E
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.E0602C12088A6C5A5970
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Parallel.Resources.9FF7C1BBE397227630A1
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Remote.7D43AB4F0C1FB0C6EA8A

... (too long to post)



some discussion of this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75638725/visual-studio-2022-adds-an-overwhelming-amount-of-folders-into-temp-is-it-saf

Those do look like Visual Studio files, probably extracted versions of references you use.
Temp files are allowed to persist as long as the application wants. No rules saying they have to clean up each reboot.

It turns out to be a bug of the VS2022 installer. After updating to the latest version, the folder disappeared.
